# Does it make a difference to use Ordinal vs Nominal in Cox Regression?

Tags: cox-model, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I'm learning about Multiple Regression (Cox and logistic) from Coursera. One of the things the instructor pointed out during the Simple Linear Regression was that if the predictor is nominal, convert the values to dummy variable, for example:

```
For tobacco use: yes, never, quit, unknown
x1 = 1 if never, 0 otherwise
x2 = 1 if quit, 0 otherwise
x3 = 1 if unknown, 0 otherwise
```

with the reference being '`yes`'.

Now, putting the same variables in Cox regression. Say there are several predictors such as tobacco, sex, marital status etc.

If we take the same example as above for tobacco, and for marital status:

```
x4 = 1 if married, 0 otherwise
x5 = 1 if unmarried, 0 otherwise
x6 = 1 if divorced, 0 otherwise
x7 = 1 if unknown, 0 otherwise
```

with `single` being the reference.

The question is, should I convert all nominal like this for Multiple Cox Regression? Is it not okay to just code it as 1,2,3, 4? Or is this done for adjusting the variables?

Comment: In addition to the issues addressed by @AdamO in the answer, you should probably not be trying to code "unknown" values in the way you propose. Handling missing data takes particular care and the best practice is to list them explicitly as not available (`NA` in R, for example). Then you can make intelligent decisions about how to proceed, for example with multiple imputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the examples you give are actually ordinal variables. For both smoking and marital status they should be coded with dummy variables for interpretation.

There is virtually no difference in the rationale or interpretation for variable coding choice in Cox or linear regression. The choice to code an ordinal variable as categorical is based on the science of the problem, not the model. If one uses nominal coding for a linear regression, mean differences are estimated for all but one of the groups. If one does so for Cox regression, log hazard ratios are estimated.

Most statistical technology can create these groups automatically. See `?factor` in R, `class` in SAS and `i.` in Stata.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm using `R` in the question. So, if I have 5 levels in `tobacco`, and 4 levels in `Marital Status`, I should be fine with fitting the cox model by doing `factor(tobacco) + factor(marital.status)`? I don't need to go through creating? This is very confusing to me. I'd appreciate if you could point me to a tutorial or give me an example.

Comment: just to be clear, here's a simple model that I used. `coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ tobacco + marital.status + age + height + weight + primary.problem + pulse + resp)` where `tobacco`, `marital.status`, `primary.problem` are categorical with 5,4,7 levels respectively, and rest are continuous. Would this be okay? Or should I create separate var for each levels as it was taught in the course? I'm very confused.

Comment: @user6401955 you should do your own data munging, making good use of the `class`, `summary`, `str`, `typeof` etc. functions to verify the coding of your variables. You should furthermore create your own dummy variables to test and verify the accuracy of the output. Do not take everything from a MOOC as dogma.